# Amazon S3 & Checksum

Tags: amazon-s3, checksum

I try to verify the integrity of a file that was uploaded to a bucket but I don't find any information of this.

In the file's headers, there is a "E-tag" but I think its not a md5 checksum.

So, how can I check if the file that I uploaded on Amazon S3 is the same that I have on my computer ?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Pretty much covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775816/how-to-get-the-md5sum-of-a-file-on-amazons-s3 , although @svetianov's answer looks a bit more complete.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using the REST API to upload an object (up to 5GB) in a single operation, then you can add the **Content-MD5** header in your **PUT** request. According the the S3 documentation for PUT, the Content-MD5 header is:

> The **base64 encoded 128-bit MD5** digest of the message (without the headers) according to RFC 1864. This header can be used as a message integrity check to verify that the data is the same data that was originally sent. Although it is optional, we recommend using the Content-MD5 mechanism as an end-to-end integrity check.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583967/how-to-encode-md5-sum-into-base64-in-bash) on how to compute a base64 encoded 128-bit MD5 digest. If you are using [s3curl](https://aws.amazon.com/code/128), you can include the computed digest in your request headers using the **--contentMd5** option.

If the md5 digest computed by Amazon upon upload completion  does not match the md5 digest you provided in the Content-MD5 header, Amazon will respond with a **BadDigest** error code.

If you are using multipart upload, the Content-MD5 header serves as an integrity check for each part individually. Once the multipart upload is finalized, Amazon does not currently provide a way to verify the integrity of the assembled file.

Comment: i developed a iphone app to upload videos to amazon , and i encoded file in to base64 encoded 128-bit MD5, upon file upload completion i receive " ErrorCode:BadDigest, Message:The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received." does this means i cant match md5 values with  my pohone and s3 server  ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471518/599390 for examples of how to do this using AWS CLI s3api commands.