# Does aws-cli confirm checksums when uploading files to S3, or do I need to manage that myself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I'm uploading data to S3 using the aws-cli (i.e. using `aws s3 cp`), does aws-cli do any work to confirm that the resulting file in S3 matches the original file, or do I somehow need to manage that myself?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618218/amazon-s3-checksum) and the Java API documentation for [putObject()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest)), it looks like it's possible to verify the MD5 checksum after upload.  However, I can't find a definitive answer on whether aws-cli actually does that.

It matters to me because I'm intending to upload GPG-encrypted files from a backup process, and I'd like some confidence that what's been stored in S3 actually matches the original.

Comment: The answer you are referring to talks about using --contentMd5 option. However, aws s3 cp does not accept  --contentMd5 as an option, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

So how did you go about achieving the checksum confirmation?I am in same situation and need help. aws s3 cp can be very confusing because you can use the --recursive option as well. So if out of 100, only two uploads failed, how do you know which one. Please comment.

Comment: @kk1957, from watching the output with `--debug` enabled, I suspect that the checksum confirmation is happening under the covers in the botocore library used by `aws cp`.  However, I haven't actually been able to find proof of that in the botocore source code.  As of now, I've just moved forward without worrying about it too much.  I did implement a post-`cp` check using `aws s3api` to confirm that all expected files exist and that they all report the correct size.  That seems like the best I can do for now.

Comment: I opened an issue with aws cli at https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/949

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the faq](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/topics/s3-faq.rst) from the aws-cli github, the checksums are checked in most cases during upload and download.

Key points for uploads:

- The AWS CLI calculates the Content-MD5 header for both standard and
  multipart uploads.
- If the checksum that S3 calculates does not match
  the Content-MD5 provided, S3 will not store the object and instead
  will return an error message back the AWS CLI.
- The AWS CLI will retry this error up to 5 times before giving up and exiting with a nonzero exit code.

Comment: I'll accept this answer if you add some details from the original document you're citing.

Comment: Do you think this is enough detail?

Answer (score 10):

The AWS support page [How do I ensure data integrity of objects uploaded to or downloaded from Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/) describes how to achieve this.

Firstly determine the base64 encoded md5sum of the file you wish to upload:

```
$ md5_sum_base64="$( openssl md5 -binary my-file | base64 )"
```

Then use the s3api to upload the file:

```
$ aws s3api put-object --bucket my-bucket --key my-file-name --body my-file-path --content-md5 "$md5_sum_base64"
```

Note the use of the `--content-md5` flag, the help for this flag states:

```
--content-md5  (string)  The  base64-encoded  128-bit MD5 digest of the part data.
```

This does not say much about **why** to use this flag, but we can find this information in the [API documentation for put object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html):

> To ensure that data is not corrupted traversing the network, use the Content-MD5 header. When you use this header, Amazon S3 checks the object against the provided MD5 value and, if they do not match, returns an error. Additionally, you can calculate the MD5 while putting an object to Amazon S3 and compare the returned ETag to the calculated MD5 value.

Using this flag causes S3 to verify that the file hash serverside matches the specified value. If the hashes match s3 will return the ETag:

```
{
    "ETag": "\"599393a2c526c680119d84155d90f1e5\""
}
```

The ETag value will usually be the hexadecimal md5sum (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775816/how-to-get-the-md5sum-of-a-file-on-amazons-s3) for some scenarios where this may not be the case).

If the hash does not match the one you specified you get an error.

```
A client error (InvalidDigest) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.
```

In addition to this you can also add the file md5sum to the file metadata as an additional check:

```
$ aws s3api put-object --bucket my-bucket --key my-file-name --body my-file-path --content-md5 "$md5_sum_base64" --metadata md5chksum="$md5_sum_base64"
```

After upload you can issue the `head-object` command to check the values.

```
$ aws s3api head-object --bucket my-bucket --key my-file-name
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "ContentType": "binary/octet-stream",
    "LastModified": "Thu, 31 Mar 2016 16:37:18 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 605,
    "ETag": "\"599393a2c526c680119d84155d90f1e5\"",
    "Metadata": {    
        "md5chksum": "WZOTosUmxoARnYQVXZDx5Q=="    
    }    
}
```

Here is a bash script that uses content md5 and adds metadata and then verifies that the values returned by S3 match the local hashes:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euf -o pipefail

# assumes you have aws cli, jq installed

# change these if required
tmp_dir="$HOME/tmp"
s3_dir="foo"
s3_bucket="stack-overflow-example"
aws_region="ap-southeast-2"
aws_profile="my-profile"

test_dir="$tmp_dir/s3-md5sum-test"
file_name="MailHog_linux_amd64"
test_file_url="https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/releases/download/v1.0.0/MailHog_linux_amd64"
s3_key="$s3_dir/$file_name"
return_dir="$( pwd )"

cd "$tmp_dir" || exit
mkdir "$test_dir"
cd "$test_dir" || exit

wget "$test_file_url"

md5_sum_hex="$( md5sum $file_name | awk '{ print $1 }' )"
md5_sum_base64="$( openssl md5 -binary $file_name | base64 )"

echo "$file_name hex    = $md5_sum_hex"
echo "$file_name base64 = $md5_sum_base64"

echo "Uploading $file_name to s3://$s3_bucket/$s3_dir/$file_name"
aws \
--profile "$aws_profile" \
--region "$aws_region" \
s3api put-object \
--bucket "$s3_bucket" \
--key "$s3_key" \
--body "$file_name" \
--metadata md5chksum="$md5_sum_base64" \
--content-md5 "$md5_sum_base64"

echo "Verifying sums match"

s3_md5_sum_hex=$( aws --profile "$aws_profile"  --region "$aws_region" s3api head-object --bucket "$s3_bucket" --key "$s3_key" | jq -r '.ETag' | sed 's/"//'g )
s3_md5_sum_base64=$( aws --profile "$aws_profile"  --region "$aws_region" s3api head-object --bucket "$s3_bucket" --key "$s3_key" | jq -r '.Metadata.md5chksum' )

if [ "$md5_sum_hex" == "$s3_md5_sum_hex" ] && [ "$md5_sum_base64" == "$s3_md5_sum_base64" ]; then
    echo "checksums match"
else
    echo "something is wrong checksums do not match:"

    cat <<EOM | column -t -s ' '
$file_name file hex:    $md5_sum_hex    s3 hex:    $s3_md5_sum_hex
$file_name file base64: $md5_sum_base64 s3 base64: $s3_md5_sum_base64
EOM

fi

echo "Cleaning up"
cd "$return_dir"
rm -rf "$test_dir"
aws \
--profile "$aws_profile" \
--region "$aws_region" \
s3api delete-object \
--bucket "$s3_bucket" \
--key "$s3_key"
```