# How to calculate Amazon's MD5 hash for http request

Tags: hash, coldfusion, amazon-web-services, coldfusion-9

Does anyone know how to calculate the MD5 hash that is needed to be used with Amazon's SubmitFeed API? I am using ColdFusion and every time I calculate the MD5 hash on my end it never matches what Amazon calculates.

Amazon responds with this error:

```
ContentMD5DoesNotMatch

the Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed (C7EF1CADB27497B46FCD6F69516F96E0) did not match the Content-MD5 we calculated for your feed (x+8crbJ0l7RvzW9pUW+W4A==)
```

I am using the built-in function that ColdFusion uses for hashing (example `hash(myStr)`). Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: You have to Base64 encode the data after you hash it. So `base64Encode(md5Hash(myStr))` See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618218/amazon-s3-checksum) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583967/how-to-encode-md5-sum-into-base64-in-bash) for more information.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the response. I've actually tried that as well <cfset hasMD5 = ToBase64(hash(xmlRequest))> and it still doesn't match Amazon's hash. I've also tried converting it to ToBase64 before hashing it just to see if that would match. Sadly it does not.

Comment: I have seen similar problems (with other api's). Most of those turned out to be caused by problems with how the content was generated, not the `hash` or `toBase64` functions. Can you post your full code and a link to the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked [this online tool](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php) and you just need to send that MD5 in base64 encoding. It is currently just hexadecimal encoded.

I'm afraid I don't know what the ColdFusion way to do that is, maybe this: 
[SHA or MD5 Digests in ColdFusion](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/203.cfm)

Answer (score 2):

```
public any function EncryptSignature(required string argValue,required string publicKey) hint="I create my own signature that I will matching later." {
    local.filters=StructNew();
    local.filters["F:publicKey"]=arguments.publicKey;
    var jMsg=JavaCast("string",arguments.argValue).getBytes("iso-8859-1");
    var thisSecretKey = getDAO().getSecretKey(local.filters).apiSecretKey;
    var jKey=JavaCast("string",thisSecretKey).getBytes("iso-8859-1");
    var key=createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec");
    var mac=createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac");
    key=key.init(jKey,"HmacSHA1");
    mac=mac.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
    mac.init(key);
    mac.update(jMsg);
    return lCase(binaryEncode(mac.doFinal(),'Hex'));
    //return Encrypt(arguments.argValue,getapiUsersDAO().getSecretKey(arguments.publicKey),'HMAC-SHA1');
    }
```

Comment: In this guy's case there is no need for java. `md5` hashing can be done with the built in CF functions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Feed must have preceding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Even adding it as a Declaration is not enough

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
new XElement("AmazonEnvelope",
...
```

if you are using XmlWriter:

```
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream))
{
    doc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
}
```

You have to save XDocument to file and then get stream from file. Only in this case XDocument preserves declaration (designed behaviour of Save() and WriteTo() methods):

```
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    doc.Save(memoryStream);

    var file = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(file))
    {
        var buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
    }

    return File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: Did you accidentally post this on the wrong thread? It does not seem to have anything to do with hashing. It also looks like C#, rather than CF or java.

Comment: It is relevant to problem: the Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed (C7EF1CADB27497B46FCD6F69516F96E0) did not match the Content-MD5 we calculated for your feed. Ignore C#, treat it as peudo-code.

Comment: There was no problem with their header. If you look at their answer from two years ago, the problem was [incorrect encoding of the hashed string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14328213/104223), so this above does not really apply, as it is about constructing xml.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to get this to work:

```
<cfset getMD5 = ToBase64(binaryDecode(hash(xmlRequest),'hex'))>
```

And bang it matched Amazons MD5 hash.

Comment: No, `ToBase64` works fine (though deprecated). You were just using it incorrectly ;) The API probably said return the hashed *bytes* as base64 ie `ToBase64( binaryDecode( hexValue, "hex" ))` That is actually very different than the original code which was doing this: `ToBase64( hexValue.getBytes("UTF-8") )`

Comment: Leigh, This is correct. I took what you suggested and it did work as well with the ToBase64. I will update my posting with the correction. Thanks.

Comment: Either should be fine (though `toBase64` is deprecated). The reason the original did not work was because it was base64 encoding the wrong thing. When you decode the hashed string *as hex*, you get 16 bytes (one byte for each pair of characters). The original did not treat the string as hex. Decoding it as a plain string produced 32 bytes (one byte for each character). That is why your final string was always so much longer than Amazon's and did not match.

Comment: I see thanks for the response! I was very helpful and I updated my posting just to make it simpler for someone else to use if they have the same issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Good idea. (I posted the explanation for similar reasons ie to explain for the next guy :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative java-way
found on http://www.kba.suche-spezialwerkzeug.de/pdf/MWSDeveloperGuide.pdf

```
public static String computeContentMD5HeaderValue(FileInputStream fis)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(fis,
            MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    while (dis.read(buffer) > 0)
        ;
    String md5Content = new String(
            org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(dis.getMessageDigest().digest())
            );
    // Effectively resets the stream to be beginning of the file via a
    // FileChannel.
    fis.getChannel().position(0);
    return md5Content;
}
```

Comment: The OP is using CF's built in `hash()` function so they do not actually need java. *the correct java-way..* There is more than one way to slice it. The previous suggestion of using `javax.crypto` would be perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 0):

This will give your desire output.

```
<cfset binaryValue = binaryDecode( 'C7EF1CADB27497B46FCD6F69516F96E0', "hex" )>
<cfset base64Value = binaryEncode( binaryValue, "base64" )>
<cfdump var="#base64Value#">
```