# How to get the checksum of a key/file on amazon using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, checksum, boto

I am writingtwo python scripts that shall move files from one bucket to another in Amazon S3 and then verify the content of the keys that have been moved. After having poured over they Key class of boto, and looking over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872679/how-to-programmatically-get-the-md5-checksum-of-amazon-s3-file-using-boto) stackoverflow question, I have found out how to pull the checksum via the "etag" after the file have been copied.

However, this only works if the file have been downlaoded/uploaded, since the verification will be done by a completely different script, I need help getting the etag from the file without actually downloading it.

Currently, the workflow is:
File one goes through a bucket and copies all the keys using boto, then it prints the path
of the output keys followed by their etag. (buckets[] is the source and destination) This works fine:

```
inbuck = conn.get_bucket(buckets[0])                                          
outbuck = conn.get_bucket(buckets[1])                                         
for inkey in inbuck.list():                                                   
    print buckets[1] + ";;" + inkey.key + ";;" + inkey.etag.replace("\"","")  
    out = Key(outbuck)                                                        
    out.key = inkey.key                                                       
    inkey.copy(outbuck,out.key,preserve_acl=True)
```

File two then reads the output from file one, checks that the key exists and should then get the etag of the key in the destination to compare with what it got as input. However, the etag for the key is always None, since it was not downloaded.

```
dstbuck = conn.get_bucket(destination[0])
dstkey = Key(dstbuck)               
dstkey.key = destination[1]    

if dstkey.exists() and dstkey.etag.replace("\"","") == destination[2]:
    PASSED.append(dstkey.key)
else:
    FAILED.append(dstkey.key)
```

Here the program crashes since the dstkey.etag is "None".
Do anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are just creating a local Key object.  No information is being retrieved from S3 about the key.  Try something like this:

```
dstbuck = conn.get_bucket(destination[0])
dstkey = bucket.get_key(destination[1])
if dstkey is None:
    FAILED.append(destination[1])
else:
    # do etag check here
```

In this way, the Key object should have the data from S3 about the object.  The `get_key` method uses the HTTP HEAD request so the body of the object will not be retrieved, only the headers.

Also, if the bucket name (i.e. destination[0]) is always the same for a given run of the program there is no need to do a `get_bucket` for each key object in the bucket.